# Browser addon to save options of a website's search page

Tags: firefox

I used Scrapbook for many years—and still
Use it on an older Mac running an older version of Firefox. As of mid-2019, is there an alternative?

For me, the key feature of Scrapbook is/was the ability to go to the “non-initial” page of a web site that had search options/parameters  on it and to select/check mark certain options/parameters and save those selections for later, repeated use.

Does anyone know of any current browser add on that does this?!

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details. Please list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for responding. I’m not sure what to add. I am an attorney, not a techie, primarily. Scrapbook is/was an add-on to Firefox that worked until, I believe, version 60(?) and some fundamental change to Firefox. It allowed web pages to be saved in a form that preserved the kind of checking off of options for later use. I think I said I use/used it with Mac OSX. I’m not sure what else to add.

Comment: Nicholas Raoul, I detailed the exact and only thing for which I use/d Scrapbook. Even before that, circa 2003, I could do the same thing with Explorer for Mac; I even think the feature was called Scrapbook—but that’s ancient history ;-)